# How to change hover color of text bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to change the color it shows on hovering in my navbar. I have the Navbar with a black background and text with #b3b3b3 color. I want it that if you hover over the text it will turn white, instead of the #b3b3b3 color, but all the CSS I tried doesn't seem to work.

this is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" style="background-color: #121212">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-    target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria- label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.navbar-nav {
  --bs-nav-link-color:#b3b3b3;
  --bs-nav-link-hover-color:white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" style="background-color: #121212">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-    target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria- label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</nav>
```

You can change values of variables